# Scheduled Export/Import for Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: import, export, crm, schedule, microsoft-dynamics

I don't know if this is the right place to ask but I give it a try. Does anyone know if there is a functionality in Dynamics CRM 2011 to create a schedule that does an automated XML Export of an entity and/or a schedule for import another file from a defined place ?

Do I have to code that myself :( ? Background for this question is the daily synchronisation between two databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is not available in CRM 2011.  There is a solution for your requirement but it is a 3rd-party application.

A Company called **Scribe** provides an integration services for all Dynamics products.

Check this link [Scribe](http://scribesoft.com/Insight)

Answer (score 4):

I'm working on this myself and having found one of the most helpful Dynamics helpers out there (see http://varghesedanny.com/)

Here is a copy & paste of our recent volley back & forth about this...

I had been leaning towards plugin + XRM whereas my other main counterpart is looking into the SSIS method...

Assumptions:
1. Assuming you have the data already in the SQL database in a format ready for consumption
2. Assuming this is a database outside of CRM

Possible solutions:

1. Using XRM methodologies, you can create an “integration logs” entity with fields around status of the integration, an entry for the data integrated and a field for error handling.  Then on update of a field (you can do this manually or using a button), trigger an asynchronous plug-in to read the database, parse the XML and pull it into CRM.
2. You can use SSIS (free with SQL Server) and add a scheduled task to kick off an integration process.  This is a bit complex to setup, but not too bad.
3. Scribe is third-party software, a bit expensive, but many of the operations are point and click and is a common tool used by many of our clients to integrate and migrate data.  You can also setup automated batch jobs to integrate in intervals.

**That being said there is workable code in PHP that my team has proven to work w/ Rollup 10 here...**

http://code.google.com/p/php-dynamics-crm-2011/source/browse/branches/RB-1.0.2/RB-1.0.0/DynamicsCRM2011.demo.php?r=69